# Listar meu app na lista de programas que podem abrir um documento

Tags: android, android-manifest

Quando recebemos um email com um arquivo anexado e clicamos sobre essa arquivo é mostrada uma lista de programas que podem abrir esse arquivo.
Como faço para meu app também aparecer nessa lista?

---

Me desculpa, sou novo na ferramenta e não vi a resposta.
Alterei meu código e mesmo assim não funciona.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Arquivos"/>
    <activity android:name=".NomeSenha" />
    <activity android:name=".Bateria" />
    <activity android:name=".Tensao"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Artur, fiz uma edição na resposta baseado nas informações acrescentadas. Adicionei outro link da documentação que fala sobre como permitir que outros aplicativos iniciem sua atividade. Testei aqui e funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

É necesário criar um `IntentFilter`, [filtros de Intenções](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html?hl=pt-br), na sua *activity* dentro do `manifest.xml`, que irá adicionar seu aplicativo à lista específica.

Um exemplo, quando é clicado no compartilhamento seria usado [`<action>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html) no [`<intent-filter>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html):

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Ficaria assim:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityNewUrl"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_new_url"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Obs.:** Você tem que verificar que tipo de arquivo quer que outras aplicações veja. Neste exemplo acima eu defino `minType` como `text/plan` e `image`, que significa que mostrará as opções quando estiver compartilhando textos ou imagens. Veja mais aqui [**como permitir que outros aplicativos iniciem sua atividade**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html?hl=pt-br).

**Imagem**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Leia mais aqui:

- [Recebimento de um intent implícito](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving)
- [Intents e filtros de intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer funcionar se no programa que lista os aquivos do celular eu selecionar a opção "compartilhar com".
Meu programa aparece na lista e é executado (agora estou com problemas para receber o arquivo mas é outro problema).
O que eu queria não é isso, é dar um clique curto sobre o nome do arquivo e o meu programa aparecer na lista.
Agora por exemplo aparece os editores de texto, visualizador de PDF e outros.
Queria que meu app constasse dessa lista, como programas que abrem esse arquivo e não apenas receber um compartilhamento.